# How many anycast ips can be created per /24 net?

Tags: ipv4, anycast

How many anycast ips can I create with one ipv4 /24 net? I know I need a whole /24 net to do anycast, but how many of those ips can I do with one? With a anycast ip address I mean one address for doke servers.

Here an example what I mean:

```
What I got:
  - 1.1.1.0/24
  - 6 Servers (a-f)

What I want to do:
  - 1.1.1.1 is for server a, b and c
  - 1.1.1.2 is for server d, e and f
```

I searched a long time but I couldnt find an answer.

Comment: This sounds a bit like a case of http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem

Comment: All of them. But you seem to have some other question. You should edit your question and clarify what is going on.

Comment: Seems like it would depend on your implementation, and other factors.  You almost certainly to tell us more.

Comment: I thought it was exact enough. The question it self were in the first line and I added an ecample to explain it. What information should I add?

Comment: An anycast address is simply a unicast address assigned to multiple devices. You could do that with every usable unicast address in a network.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Anycast means you are announcing a route to your assigned /24 via BGP from multiple physical networks on the Internet. In general, the closest (on the network, not necessarily physical distance) one to any given user's ISP gets used for any given connection.

Because the entire /24 is announced, *every usable address in the block is anycast*.

Comment: SoIf I understood it right,  I can buy one net and sell different anycast ips for different users with different servers?

Comment: @Florian It has to be PI space, which is almost impossible to get anymore in IPv4 addresses, _and_ your potential customers have to colocate in your datacenters. There are one or two companies doing this already for people who want less than a /24, but it's not something you're going to set up in a weekend...

Comment: I know that it isnt easy, Im just interested in it. ^^ As far as I know /24 is the minimum for anycast and there are still companies who sell that; Which companies are you talking about?

Comment: buyvm.net sells it,  and requires a server in every pop, as is advertised in all pops